# Why is Time Capsule archive taking forever?

Tags: time-capsule, archive

I've got a Time Capsule, which I use to back up two machines in my house, over WiFi. Backups have started failing, so I decided to archive what's on the disk now, wipe the disk, and start from scratch.

I've got about 1.1 TB of data on the Time Capsule. I bought a 2 TB USB drive (Western Digital WDBU6Y0020BBK), built a journaled file system on it, plugged it into the TC, and started an archive. That was almost two days ago. It's done with 260 GB, and estimating a week +/- a couple of days to finish. It's continuing to make progress, but at an astonishingly slow pace.

WTF could it possibly be doing? If I did the math right, that's 1.5 MB/s, which is under 1% of the USB 2.0 rate.

I do dual backups (TC and backblaze), so I'm not too worried.

Comment: You're assuming that your Time Capsule is able to use the full duplex speed. Max speed of USB-2.0 is 480 Mbps (60 Megabytes per second). Max speed of USB-3 is 5 Gbits/second (625 MegaBytes/second).  I'm not sure if Time Capsule differs in any respect from Time Machine, so I cannot comment on that

Comment: Also, is this the first time that you're backing up to this disk (volume)?  A first time backup will naturally take longer.  When a subsequent backup is made Time Machine (or in the case of Windows, Windows Backup) makes a backup that is just the changed files, and uses some version of linking to make it look like the whole drive has been backed up every time

Comment: I'm not talking about the backup taking a long time.  I'm talking about the archiving from the TC internal disk to the external disk I plugged into the TC USB port.

Comment: Still, you'll be lucky if you hit anywhere near half USB-max speeds (the lower of the TC USB and Hard-drive USB), as the hard drive has to read, write (and sometimes also provide power) on the same cord

Comment: Also note that a Time Machine backup is composed of, quite literally, hundreds of thousands of files. And just enumarating all of them takes a long time. I am not surprised it is taking this long.